# Is there any GUI editor for MetaFont?

Tags: fonts, gui, wysiwyg

Is there any WYSIWYG GUI editor for MetaFont (`.mf` files)? I have google-ed but didn't get any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) has partial support, but it may depend on what you're trying to do. (It think it may import them but not save/export them?--I've never tried.)